# execute program on port connect to windows

Tags: windows

is there a program that listens to a specific port and executes an arbitrary executeable on incoming connection to that port?

the reason: sometimes itunes is not running, then id like to be able to start it with remote.

Answer (score 3):

[`xinetd`](http://www.xinetd.org/) is a Unix daemon that listens on one or more ports and launches programs (generally servers or other daemons) when connections come in to those ports.  It is available on [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and can be installed as a Windows service with the `cygrunsrv` utility:

```
$ xinetd-config
$ cygrunsrv -I xinetd -p /usr/sbin/xinetd -d 'CYGWIN xinetd' -a '-stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid'
$ cygrunsrv -S xinetd
```

I don't know that it is ideal for your end goal of remote-controlling iTunes, but it *can* be used to listen to arbitrary ports and launch arbitrary programs.  I think it could suit your needs if you get creative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what elhombre meant, not a remote control solution like suggested by the others.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) is secure and fairly easy to setup on windows.  Once you have the ssh service running on your windows machine, you could create a script that ssh's into your windows server, starts itunes, then exits.

Answer (score -1):

If you need a simple way *just* to launch iTunes remotely, you can use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).  The command line you would be interested in would be:

```
psexec \\computername -i -d -u YourUserName -p YourPassword "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"

-i : Run this program so it can be seen on the desktop.
-d : Exit psexec once the program has been launched.
-p : If you omit this, it will prompt for your password instead
      of typing it in the clear or storing it in a batch file.
```